# Having some problems saving/displaying an image in MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, image, asp.net-mvc-4, arrays

I have searched around for a while now with no joy. I am trying to save an image to my SQL db as a byte array, then I am trying to display it later. The display part is not working. I don't know if it's a problem with the save or the display. The save appears to be working ok, I can see 'Binary Data' in my SQL table. Any suggestions?

What's happening is that I get a broken image icon on my page. Even if I manually goto the URL e.g. .../Treatments/LoadImage/14 it's broken.

**Model contains this in my table definition:**

```
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
```

**Create View:**

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="file" name="photo" />
</div>
```

**Create Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Photo")]Treatment treatment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            treatment.Photo = GetByteArrayFromFile();
            treatment.WebOrder = db.Treatments.Count();
            db.Treatments.Add(treatment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.TreatmentTypeId = new SelectList(db.TreatmentTypes, "Id", "Name", treatment.TreatmentTypeId);
        return View(treatment);
    }

    private byte[] GetByteArrayFromFile() {
        int fileLength = Request.Files["photo"].ContentLength;
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[fileLength];

        return byteArray;
    }
```

**Display View:**

```
    <div class="display-label">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Photo)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        <img src="@Url.Action("LoadImage", new { Id = Model.Id })" />
    </div>
```

**LoadImage Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult LoadImage(int Id) {
        byte[] bytes = db.Treatments.Find(Id).Photo;
        return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

I have added:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Treatments", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    // View Code Omitted
}
```

to my Create view.

Is there something elementary wrong with my code? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my GetByteArrayFromFile Method. My original method above returned an array of zeros only. Using this, I fixed my issue:

```
        private byte[] GetByteArrayFromFile() {
            WebImage image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
            byte[] byteArray = image.GetBytes();

            return byteArray;
        }
```